# Let $\{a_j\} \ j \in \mathbb{N} $ a sequence of numbers. Prove that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_j\} \ j \in \mathbb{N} $ a sequence of numbers. Prove that

$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j<n}(1-\frac{j}{n})a_j $ iff serie of the left converge

Comment: really, I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the fact that: $a_n \to 0, s_n = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_j$. Thus:  $S_n = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\dfrac{j}{n}\right)a_j=\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{(n-j)a_j}{n}= s_{n-1}-\dfrac{n-1}{n}\cdot \left(\dfrac{a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)-\dfrac{n-2}{n}\cdot \left(\dfrac{a_2+a_3+\cdots +a_{n-1}}{n-2}\right)-\cdots - \dfrac{n-k}{n}\cdot \left(\dfrac{a_k+a_{k+1}+\cdots + a_{n-1}}{n-k}\right)+\cdots -\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{n}\to \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j-0-0\cdots - 0=\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j$, by using Cesaro's theorem for each term of the sum on the right side. Note